# Multiple columns creation in one swoop?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a `data.frame`

```
DF = structure(list(AE = c(148, 1789, 1223, 260, 1825, 37, 1442, 484, 
10, 163, 1834, 254, 445, 837, 721, 1904, 1261, 382, 139, 213), 
    FW = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("LYLR", 
    "OCXG", "BIYX"), class = "factor"), CP = c("WYB/NXO", "HUK/NXO", 
    "HUK/WYB", "HUK/NXO", "WYB/NXO", "HUK/WYB", "HUK/NXO", "HUK/NXO", 
    "WYB/NXO", "HUK/NXO", "WYB/NXO", "HUK/NXO", "HUK/WYB", "WYB/NXO", 
    "HUK/WYB", "WYB/NXO", "WYB/NXO", "HUK/WYB", "WYB/NXO", "WYB/NXO"
    ), SD = c(1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
    -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("AE", "FW", "CP", "SD"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Or in human readable format:

```
     AE   FW      CP SD
1   148 LYLR WYB/NXO  1
2  1789 BIYX HUK/NXO  1
3  1223 OCXG HUK/WYB -1
4   260 BIYX HUK/NXO  1
5  1825 BIYX WYB/NXO  1
6    37 LYLR HUK/WYB  1
7  1442 OCXG HUK/NXO  1
8   484 BIYX HUK/NXO -1
9    10 OCXG WYB/NXO  1
10  163 OCXG HUK/NXO  1
11 1834 BIYX WYB/NXO -1
12  254 OCXG HUK/NXO -1
13  445 BIYX HUK/WYB  1
14  837 OCXG WYB/NXO -1
15  721 LYLR HUK/WYB -1
16 1904 BIYX WYB/NXO  1
17 1261 LYLR WYB/NXO -1
18  382 LYLR HUK/WYB  1
19  139 LYLR WYB/NXO  1
20  213 BIYX WYB/NXO  1
```

As a data.table,

```
DT = data.table(DF)
setkey(DT, CP)
```

Now consider the following two operations:

```
  DT[, amount_sum_fh   :=  DT[.(CP = CP), 
                     on = .(CP), mean(AE * SD), by=.EACHI]$V1]
  DT[,  amount_sum_sh   :=  DT[.(CP = CP), 
                     on = .(CP), mean(AE), by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

Is there a way to do them in one swoop?

Comment: In this case, there's no need for a join `DF[, \`:=\`(x = mean(AE*SD), y = mean(AE)), by=CP][]`. Generally, I guess a join will only be needed if there's an inequality involved in the `on=` merge conditions, or a separate table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In question, comments, and answers three approaches have been presented so far:

- The OP [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43392267/3817004) code which involves joins.
- Frank [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392267/multiple-columns-creation-in-one-swoop#comment73846229_43392267) a `data.table` approach without join.
- Zelazny7 [gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43392564/3817004) a base R answer.

To decide which is the *fastest* of the alternatives, the `microbenchmark` package can be used:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(DF)
setkey(DT, CP)

mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  OP = {
    DT[, amount_sum_fh   :=  DT[.(CP = CP), 
                                on = .(CP), mean(AE * SD), by=.EACHI]$V1]
    DT[,  amount_sum_sh   :=  DT[.(CP = CP), 
                                 on = .(CP), mean(AE), by=.EACHI]$V1]
  },
  Frank = DT[, `:=`(amount_sum_fh = mean(AE*SD), amount_sum_sh = mean(AE)), by = CP],
  DF = transform(DF, 
                 amount_sum_fh = ave(AE * SD, CP, FUN = mean),
                 amount_sum_sh = ave(AE, CP, FUN = mean)),
  times = 100L
)

mb
#Unit: microseconds
#  expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#    OP 4090.271 4288.2800 4614.9625 4417.2700 4633.7880 7470.179   100   c
# Frank  548.833  612.9355  687.6306  643.5160  711.5745 1142.041   100 a  
#    DF  725.649  769.8660  840.5960  811.9315  870.3365 1376.425   100  b
```

Even with the rather small sample size, Frank's `data.table` version is about 25% faster than the base R approach.

Comment: Yours is clearly the best answer as it uses `data.table`. I like to provide base R answers for those who don't want the overhead of additional packages.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it using base R:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, 
  amount_sum_fh=ave(AE * SD, CP, FUN = mean),
  amount_sum_sh=ave(AE, CP, FUN = mean))
```

However the `data.frame` isn't sorted by CP.

```
> DF2
     AE   FW      CP SD amount_sum_fh amount_sum_sh
1   148 LYLR WYB/NXO  1      34.11111      907.8889
2  1789 BIYX HUK/NXO  1     486.00000      732.0000
3  1223 OCXG HUK/WYB -1    -216.00000      561.6000
4   260 BIYX HUK/NXO  1     486.00000      732.0000
5  1825 BIYX WYB/NXO  1      34.11111      907.8889
6    37 LYLR HUK/WYB  1    -216.00000      561.6000
7  1442 OCXG HUK/NXO  1     486.00000      732.0000
8   484 BIYX HUK/NXO -1     486.00000      732.0000
9    10 OCXG WYB/NXO  1      34.11111      907.8889
10  163 OCXG HUK/NXO  1     486.00000      732.0000
11 1834 BIYX WYB/NXO -1      34.11111      907.8889
12  254 OCXG HUK/NXO -1     486.00000      732.0000
13  445 BIYX HUK/WYB  1    -216.00000      561.6000
14  837 OCXG WYB/NXO -1      34.11111      907.8889
15  721 LYLR HUK/WYB -1    -216.00000      561.6000
16 1904 BIYX WYB/NXO  1      34.11111      907.8889
17 1261 LYLR WYB/NXO -1      34.11111      907.8889
18  382 LYLR HUK/WYB  1    -216.00000      561.6000
19  139 LYLR WYB/NXO  1      34.11111      907.8889
20  213 BIYX WYB/NXO  1      34.11111      907.8889
```